# File.canWrite() returns false on some devices although WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission provided

Tags: java, android

File.canWrite() returns false on some devices although
 
permission provided.

In my application I need to write data to External Sd Card. However this works on some devices but fails on
some other . 
for instance 
Works : Limebox  Internal Flash, SDCard, android OS: 2.3.3 
    Samsung  Sdcard, extSdcard, android OS: 4.0.3

Fails : Leoxys  sdcard, extsd android OS:4.0.3

How to find out Android Compatible Devices Dynamically i.e 
which allow External SD card write operation.  myfile.canWrite

Detail: 
The getExternalSD() is an user defined function which will return the external sdcard path

In my case the external Sdcard path is "/mnt/extSdcard" (or) "/mnt/extsd"
I am finding the external sdcard path by reading the file "/system/etc/vold.fstab"

Here is some code Snippet : it creates a folder in the external sdcard. 
On some devices , myfile.canWrite() returns False and I am unable create folder.

```
String sdcardpath = getExternalSD();
    System.out.println("the sdcard path is:"+sdcardpath.trim().toString());
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.append("the sd card path is:"+sdcardpath);

    File myfile = new File(sdcardpath);
    tv.append("\n the extsd is readable or not:"+myfile.canRead());
    tv.append("\n \n the extsd is writable or not:"+myfile.canWrite());
    if(myfile.canWrite()){
        File testfile = new File(sdcardpath, "test");
        if(testfile.exists()){

        }else{
            boolean mkdir = testtlie.mkdirs();
            if(mkdir == true){
            tv.append("\n\n the path is:"+sdcardpath.trim().toString()+"/myfile");
            }else{
                tv.append("\n File does not have permissions");
            }
        }

    }else{
        System.out.println("the external sd card does not have write permissions");
        tv.append("\n\n the external sd card does not have write permissions");
    }
```

xml file snippets.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I would like to get suggestions on
a. Are there any apis that lets the Developer know if the Devices is Truely Android compatible ?
b. Why there are difference in behaviour on different hardware devices. Is this related to firmware ?
c. Are there any alternate ways to achieve write on this kind of hardware ?

I alreday tried modifying permissions of file "platform.xml" under /system/etc/premissions/ using terminal Emulator
But I am not able to open the file in write mode

By default android provides Environment.getEnternalStorageDirectory().
But the library returns the "/mnt/sdcard" which will be the internal memory in some devices.

Your inputs will be greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 4):

> File.canWrite() returns false on some devices although permission provided.

That is because there is no permission for what you are trying to do.

> In my application i need to write data to External Sd Card

Android applications do not necessarily have access to "External Sd Card". Not all devices even *have* "External Sd Card". Hence, your "need" is flawed and needs to be replaced.

> How to find out Android Compatible Devices Dynamically i.e which allow External SD card write operation. myfile.canWrite

You don't.

> In my case the external Sdcard path is "/mnt/extSdcard" (or) "/mnt/extsd"

Those paths may exist on some devices for some firmware versions. Whether there is "External Sd Card" is up to the device manufacturer. Whether it is mounted, and if so, at what point, is up to the device manufacturer. What the permissions are is up to the device manufacturer. And those answers may change at any time, on any device, with a firmware upgrade.

> I am finding the external sdcard path by reading the file "/system/etc/vold.fstab"

That is incrementally better than random guessing, but you are going well beyond the scope of the Android SDK.

> On some devices , myfile.canWrite() returns False and I am unable to create folder.

Of course.

> By default android provides Environment.getEnternalStorageDirectory().

This returns a `File` pointing to external storage -- what the user will have access to if they attach a USB cable between the device and a host computer and mount external storage as a drive or volume.

> a. Are there any apis that lets the Developer know if the Devices is Truely Android compatible ?

What you are trying to do is not "Truely Android compatible". The devices are fine -- your expectations are not. Please fix your expectations.

> Why there are difference in behaviour on different hardware devices.

Anything that is outside the scope of the Android SDK is up to device manufacturers. They can do what they want.

> Are there any alternate ways to achieve write on this kind of hardware ?

Nothing that will be reliable. Just use official external storage (e.g., getExternalFilesDir()). Or, build your own ROM mod that you control, so you dictate the terms of what non-standard mount points exist and what their read/write permissions are, and use that ROM mod on whatever devices you wish to and can.

Comment: Environment.getEnternalStorageDirectory() is useless, on quite a few devices we have it returns the internal SD. I'm having the same issue as the original poster. A custom app (not for an Android phone or tablet, but a very specific device) for a specific customer and unable to write to any of the attached storage devices (while other apps can)

Comment: @TimothyP: Then talk to the manufacturer of the "very specific device" and *ask them* what to do. It is rather unlikely that the manufacturer in question will notice your StackOverflow comments, so I would recommend calling them or otherwise using their existing customer support mechanisms.

Comment: Many devices do not return the info properly, the single device was an example, just to point that 'Environment.getEnternalStorageDirectory()" is actually not reliable.

Comment: @TimothyP: It is reliable. It may not be returning what you would like it to, in which case you are welcome to build your own device or your own ROM mod, which can behave how you want them to. "Environment.getEnternalStorageDirectory() is useless, on quite a few devices we have it returns the internal SD" -- external storage has never meant removable storage. It so happens that on some older devices external storage was removable, but that was never the definition, as is covered in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: That's what I learned today as well. Wanted to add that for rooted devices there is a workaround: http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/08/26/how-to-allow-apps-to-write-files-to-usb-mass-storage-devices-in-android/ (as well as witching the internal and external mounts using fstab) Maybe the info can help someone.

Comment: This answer makes a lot of sense.  My personal experience confirms that the Android permission is unrelated to the external SD card access.  I have an Android 4.2 device. One ROM version does not allow external SD write access, another version does with exactly the same app of the same configuration.

Answer (score 1):

to your question b: because (unfortunately) there's still no real standardization on Android, APIs may vary by manufacturer and you can often face device-specific problems. A good example is the getData() method which returns null on Samsung 2.3.x devices.

`Environment.getEnternalStorageDirectory()` - I suppose this will return internal memory directory only on devices which do not have an sd-card so I don't see a problem there.

Comment: Actually this returns the internal SD on devices like the Mele A1000 and Cubieboard even though there is an SD card

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Commonsware,Maver1ck for your inputs and advise.

> Android applications do not necessarily have access to "External Sd Card".Not all devices even have "External Sd Card". Hence, your "need" is flawed and needs to be replaced

The Android  app in question  is custom application for a specific need and is not 
intended to be typical android market app. This app fetches the data from a network server
and stores it onto external Sdcard. As the data is Huge ,phone memory is too small
for the same.

> Nothing that will be reliable. Just use official external storage (e.g., getExternalFilesDir()). Or, build your own ROM mod that you control, so you dictate the terms of what non-standard mount points exist and what their read/write permissions are, and use that ROM mod on whatever devices you wish to and can.

I will study on the ROM Modules and pursue this problem further.